# libjpeg-turbo8-dev : Conflicts: libjpeg62-dev but 1:6b2-2 is to be installed

Tags: python-2.7, ubuntu-16.04

This is the error I am getting when running this command-

> sudo apt-get install libevent-1.4* libevent-core-1.4* libevent-dev
>   libjpeg8 libjpeg8-dev zlib1g-dev libpng12-dev libjpeg62 libjpeg62-dev

"""

*

python-imaging is already the newest version (3.1.2-0ubuntu1.1). libmemcached-dev is already the newest version (1.0.18-5+deb.sury.org~xenial+2).

Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable distribution that some required packages have not yet been created or been moved out of Incoming.

The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:

libjpeg-turbo8-dev : Conflicts: libjpeg62-dev but 1:6b2-2 is to be installed

E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.*

"""

Comment: I am getting the same error - struggling to find a solution to this

Answer (score 1):

You can use aptitude instead of apt-get to deal with this problem. It worked for me.Run the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get install aptitude
sudo aptitude install libjpeg62-dev
```

The solution was given at:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/590119/libjpeg8-dev-unmet-dependencies-what-should-i-do-to-fix-this

This works because aptitude is more able in resolving conflicts, it suggests you solutions for such scenarios. For more detailed differences between apt-get and aptitude, follow the link:
https://www.tecmint.com/difference-between-apt-and-aptitude/

Comment: Could you please improve your answer by giving an example of the command, and explaining in a few words why you believe it will work? Keep the link as a reference.